# Увеличение производительности android studio

Tags: android-studio

Студия тормозит, можно увеличить ее производительность?И почему она использует много памяти?

Comment: конкретизируйте вопрос. На какой машине используется студия (характеристики). Используется ли там что-то параллельно. В какие моменты она использует много памяти? Много памяти это сколько? При каких действиях она тормозит? В чем выражается торможение? Какой код исполняется (если исполняется) в эти моменты? Сейчас ваш вопрос звучит так "почему машина едет медленно, можно ли ехать быстрее? почему она тратит много бензина?"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Купите SSD диск и несколько планок оперативки.
2. Обновляйте Gradle до последней версии.
3. Также можно поставить другой емулятор всместо стандартного, кторый жрёт меньше памяти.
4. В gradle.properties прописать:

`org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true`

Если грузит проц для процесса `studio64.exe` поставить приоритет Low.

Comment: Что сделают эти команды в gradle если их прописать?Расскажите попродробней

Comment: org.gradle.parallel=true
Эта строчка позволяет выполнять компиляцию нескольких модулей одновременно, это даст прирост производительности только в случае, если у вас сложный проект со множеством модулей. org.gradle.configureondemand=true Gradle сможет проверять изменения на уровне проекта и повторно использовать конфигурацию.
org.gradle.daemon=true
 позволяет сэкономить время, нужное для старта Gradle, так как он становится фоновым процессом.